# Local LAN Backup Freeware

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, backup, lan

I have a Windows server running as a NAS / mediapc / a few other things.
That's being backed up offsite to BackBlaze.
Rather than paying for multiple BB subscriptions to backup my PC, laptop, wife's laptop + a few other devices I have laying around, I am backing them up to the NAS, then that gets backed up as one large account

Previously I was using crashplan to do the local backup, Also allowed me to share my backup with external family members.
However Crashplan has started giving me issues (I think they are removing it all together now, as they got rid of the public part a while ago, and went business only)

So I'm looking for an alternative.

All the ones I have come across either have a complicated setup (Want something easy I can send to family to backup to me)
Don't have a server/client architecture / only backup to the cloud
Or just do file copy and don't do any dedupe / history (version checking, whatever its called)

Does anyone have any good ideas for what I can use

Requirements:

- Windows server
- Windows / Linux clients
- Easy to install / setup client
- Set and forget (No needing to go in and push sync every time)
- Free

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also use BackBlaze. It will allow you to back up external drives too. I currently have 7 or 8tB backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are switching to UrBackup from CrashPlan. It is not peer-2-peer, but client/server and

- It's easy to setup, including on Windows
- Has a LAN mode where it automatically discovers clients
- Ability to create pre-configured client executables on the server
- Free software
- Automatic flexible backup scheduling

Problem you might encounter:

It is best used with a next generation file system like ZFS or btrfs. It also works with NTFS, but isn't as efficient. If you run it on a Windows Server OS you might get good results in combination with the Windows Server Dedup.

https://www.urbackup.org/

Answer (score 0):

Rsync is a very good solution that does your backups over wifi from lots of platforms, and does it via bit torrent mechanism so it's very forgiving of network hiccups.  If you're using Windows for a NAS, you might consider instead FreeNAS (which you can test out by booting from a USB stick), rsync is included.

See also [this previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35336/why-hasnt-rsync-caught-on-in-the-windows-world)  for details if you're feeling windows-impaired about it.